# sql query group by date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with below data -

```
StartDate   EndDate    Amount    
2/1/2016    4/30/2016   2.265
2/1/2016    12/31/2099  16.195
5/1/2016    12/31/2099  37.75
```

I am trying to write a query to sum the amount on date range and give me below result

```
StartDate   EndDate    Amount
2/1/2016    4/30/2016   18.46
5/1/2016    12/31/2099  53.945
```

The result needs to be distinct date range with amount summed for that date range. As in above example, row 2 has dates that overlap row 1 and 3. So the row 2 amount needs to be added in row 1 and row 3.

I am writing this query on sql server 2012, Please advise on what approach I should take.

Below is query to generate sample data

```
 SELECT * INTO #tmp_GridResults_1
FROM (
SELECT N'2016-02-01 00:00:00.000' AS [StartDate], N'2016-04-30 00:00:00.000' AS [EndDate], N'2.265' AS [Amount] UNION ALL
SELECT N'2016-02-01 00:00:00.000' AS [StartDate], N'2099-12-31 00:00:00.000' AS [EndDate], N'16.195' AS [Amount] UNION ALL
SELECT N'2016-05-01 00:00:00.000' AS [StartDate], N'2099-12-31 00:00:00.000' AS [EndDate], N'37.75' AS [Amount] ) t;
SELECT [StartDate], [EndDate], [Amount]
FROM #tmp_GridResults_1
```

Comment: You should add more detail to your description, for example by what you want to group, from what i can see you want to group by the StartDate, is that right?

Comment: Give us more details in what you want to achieve, or sample with more data would help.

Comment: Apologize for not putting enough details. I have a table with different date range and the result needs to be distinct date range with amount summed for that date range. As in above example, row 2 is has dates that overlap row 1 and 3. So the row 2 amount needs to be added in row 1  and row 3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to group with both StartDate and EndDate. However, if you use just StartDate and Amount you can try this:

> select StartDate,sum(Amount) as Amount from #tmp_GridResults_1 group by StartDate

This will give you the grouping of Amount by StartDate.

Answer (score 0):

From my previews comment i think you want to group by StartDate, in that case you can use:

```
SELECT
mt.StartDate,
SUM(Amount) AS 'Amount'
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE mt.StartDate BETWEEN
'2016-05-18 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-06-20 00:00:00.000' --your date range
GROUP BY StartDate
```

However you need to specify in your question how you want to group them, because with 2 date fields you can group the following ways:

```
GROUP BY StartDate --groups records that have the same StartDate

GROUP BY EndDate   --groups records that have the same EndDate

GROUP BY StartDate, EndDate --groups records that have same StartDate and EndDate
```

Also with 2 date fields your date range can vary a lot.

```
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN @sd AND @ed --will get records whose start date is inside the provided range

WHERE EndDate BETWEEN @sd AND @ed --will get records whose end date is inside the provided range

WHERE StartDate >= @sd AND EndDate <= @ed -- will get records that started and ended inside the provided date range

WHERE StartDate BETWEEN @sd AND @ed OR EndDate BETWEEN @sd AND @ed
--this last one will get records whose StartDate or EndDate are inside the provided date range
```

based on this you can build the query that you need, but with the provided data in your question its still ambiguous what you want to achieve, you need to be more specific and provide more data in order to produce an exact answer to your question.

One more thing to add is that if you take into account time it will not group them if the date is the same but time is different i.e.

```
'2016-05-18 00:00:00.000'
'2016-05-18 01:01:01.001'
--these dates will not be grouped
```

Comment: Apologize for not putting enough details. I have a table with different date range and the result needs to be distinct date range with amount summed for that date range. As in above example, row 2 is has dates that overlap row 1 and 3. So the row 2 amount needs to be added in row 1 and row 3.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give the required result :-

```
select StartDate,EndDate,SUM(Amount) over (partition by StartDate) AS Amount into #t1    
from table_name
select StartDate,EndDate,SUM(Amount) over (partition by EndDate) AS Amount  into #t2 
from table_name


select * from (

select distinct P.StartDate,P.EndDate,P.Amount from (
select StartDate,MIN(EndDate) EndDate,Amount from #t1
group by StartDate,Amount) P
JOIN (
select MIN(StartDate) StartDate,EndDate,Amount from #t2
group by EndDate,Amount) Q on P.StartDate=Q.StartDate OR P.EndDate=Q.EndDate
where P.Amount>=Q.Amount

UNION

select distinct P.StartDate,P.EndDate,P.Amount from (
select MIN(StartDate) StartDate,EndDate,Amount from #t2
group by EndDate,Amount) P
JOIN (
select StartDate,MIN(EndDate) EndDate,Amount from #t1
group by StartDate,Amount) Q on P.StartDate=Q.StartDate OR  P.EndDate=Q.EndDate
where P.Amount>=Q.Amount

) A
```

Just Replace table_name by the table for which you want result, Let me know in case of any confusion